# Updating the a text file during a vsts release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a requirement to update a text file during the release phase in VSTS depending on which environment the solution is being deployed too. I am a complete beginner to this.

I've looked at variables but I'm not clear on whether this will solve this particular problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of this text file? What data do you want to put into it?

Comment: @DanielMann Its a text files so we want to put text into it!

Comment: That is not helpful. I'm asking for a reason: Your end-goal is directly relevant to giving you a useful response. If you're trying to manage configuration files, the answers that have been given are bad approaches.

Comment: What's the result if you try it with my solution?

Comment: If I wanted to update configurations I would have asked about updating config files. So too reiterate I want to update a text file with text

Comment: I did have a look at the replace tokens which I think would have worked but in the end we decided to store the different files in azure blob storage and download the relevant file for each environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tasks that can update the file during the release, such as RegexReplace Build task (As rickjerrity mentioned), [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) etc…, you also can do it programming (e.g. PowerShell) during release.

Steps:

1. Add the environments with same name for each environment (Set Scope)

[image]

2. Using that variable in task.

Comment: Sir, how can i do it programmatically using powershell if consider same solution you provided.